# Convert float seconds to seconds and nanoOfSecond for java-time

Tags: clojure, java-time

I have a floating point value representing seconds. I'd like to split it into two integers representing whole seconds and nanoseconds in order to pass it as the last two arguments to the [`java.time.ZonedDateTime.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-java.time.ZoneId-) constructor.

This is my current approach, but I worry that I might be needlessly losing precision or recreating some sort of existing java-time functionality:

```
;;seconds >= 0 and < 60
(defn seconds-and-nanos
  [seconds]
  (cond
    (integer? seconds) [seconds 0]
    (float? seconds) [(int seconds) (int (* (mod seconds (int seconds)) 1000000000))]))


;;repl> (seconds-and-nanos 3.4)
;;[3 399999999]
```

Is there a better way? Thanks for any help.

**Update**, this appears to work better, but still curious if it could be improved:

```
;;seconds >= 0 and < 60
(defn seconds-and-nanos
  [seconds]
  (cond
    (integer? seconds)
    [seconds 0]
    
    (float? seconds)
    (let [whole (int seconds)
          nano (Math/round (* (- seconds whole) 1000000000))]
      (if (= nano 1000000000)
        [whole (- nano 1)]
        [whole nano]))))

;;repl> (seconds-and-nanos 3.4)
;;[3 400000000]
;;repl> (seconds-and-nanos 3.9999999999)
;;[3 999999999]
;;repl> (seconds-and-nanos 3.999999999)
;;[3 999999999]
```

**Update 2**

Per the accepted answer and comment, and per some of my own experience repurposing this code, I consolidated to:

```
(defn seconds-and-nanos
  [seconds]
  (let [whole (long (Math/floor seconds))
        fraction (- seconds whole)
        nano (* fraction 1000000000)
        nano (cond
               (float? nano) (Math/round nano)
               (instance? clojure.lang.BigInt nano) (long nano)
               :else nano)]
    (if (= nano 1000000000)
      [whole (- nano 1)]
      [whole nano])))
```

`seconds` are no longer constrained to 60 or fewer. The `if (= nano 1000000000)` block is highly context dependent and could be eliminated or rewritten as needed; for my use cases I decided this is a rare enough edge case (arising only when somehow dealing with `seconds` of well beyond nano precision, which is already dubious) that I decided to go the much more convenient path of always rounding down to avoid adding a whole second and potentially cascading up every other unit (minute, hour etc).

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Omit the `cond`.  `(let [total-nanos (Math/round (* seconds 1000000000.0))])` and then return `[(/ total-nanos 1000000000) (% total-nanos 1000000000)]`. I am guessing at the syntax since I don’t know Clojure. I hope you can get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like the following, beginning from [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s])
  (:import
    [java.time Instant]))

(def SECOND->NANOS 1.0e9)

(s/defn epoch-sec->Instant :- Instant
  "Accepts a floating point value of epoch second and converts to a java.time.Instant"
  [epoch-seconds :- s/Num]
  (assert (<= 0 epoch-seconds)) ; throw for negative times for simplicity
  (let [esec-dbl      (double epoch-seconds)
        esec-whole    (Math/floor esec-dbl)
        esec-fraction (- esec-dbl esec-whole)
        esec-nanos    (Math/round (* esec-fraction SECOND->NANOS))
        result        (Instant/ofEpochSecond (long esec-whole) (long esec-nanos))]
    result))
```

with unit test

```
(verify
  (throws? (epoch-sec->Instant -1))
  (is= "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" (str (epoch-sec->Instant 0.0)))
  (is= "1970-01-01T00:00:00.100Z" (str (epoch-sec->Instant 0.1)))
  (is= "1970-01-01T00:00:00.999990Z" (str (epoch-sec->Instant 0.99999)))
  (is= "1970-01-01T00:00:00.999999900Z" (str (epoch-sec->Instant 0.9999999))))
```

Then, you can build a ZDT from the `Instant` value using the static method

```
static ZonedDateTime  ofInstant(Instant instant, ZoneId zone)
```

You can find a large number of conversion and convenience functions for `java.time` [already written here](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/22.08.03/api/tupelo.java-time).